# NoReverseMatch Error when adding slug to url

Tags: python, django, django-urls

quite new to Django and Python. Hoping to get some help on what went wrong with the below code. Basically, I am trying to create a url with and id and a slugfield e.g. `something.com/1/arts-and-crafts`.

Stucked and getting a NoReverseMatch error below:

**Reverse for 'category' with arguments '(2, u'arts-and-crafts')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P\d+)/[-\w]+/$', '(?P\d+)/$']**

Below is the code that I am using, would greatly appreciate any help in understanding what went wrong:

**template html**

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
          {% for category in categories %}
            {% if forloop.counter < 10 %}
              <li><a href="{% url 'category' category.id category.slug %}">
                {{ category.cat_name}}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

**url.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<cat_id>\d+)/[-\w]+/$', 'guides.views.category', name='category'),
```

**views.py**

```
def category(request, cat_id):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    guides = Guide.objects.filter(category__id=cat_id).order_by("created_date").reverse()
    is_featured = Guide.objects.filter(category__id=cat_id).filter(featured=True)
    selected_category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=cat_id)
    return render(request, 'guides/category.html', {'categories': categories, 'guides': guides, 'is_featured': is_featured, 'selected_category': selected_category})
```

Comment: I suggest you to edit the title of your question.

Comment: Also, could you add your view code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL doesn't capture the slug as a parameter, so it can't be used in the reverse call. Either change the second pattern to `(?P<slug>[-\w]+)` or don't use `category.id` in the `{% url %}` tag.

Comment: Kinda new at Django, but is it required to capture the slug as an argument with `(?P<slug>[-\w]+)`? As I do not really require to pass it as an argument to my view. This does however seem to resolve the issue. =)

Comment: No, as I say: if you don't want to capture it, don't use it in the {% url %} tag.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question as I am really not familiar. How can I then dynamically create a <a> with a href="something/slug" without using the {% url %} tag? Thanks!